# Unable to reach the bottom of a dialog window

Tags: gnome, 20.04, window, resize, dialog

I'm unable to reach the bottom of this window. I can't resize/reshape it unlike other windows. It's a part of the software Cytoscape used for studying protein networks/interactions. I'm new to linux, I don't know how to solve this issue.

[image: Image link]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes indeed, windows may have been created too large for certain screen resolutions. And if it is a dialog, there may be no possibility to resize. Thus, it is as such impossible to reach some controls.

There are two ways you still can display the bottom of the window

1. With the mouse and a modifier key

There is a "Window Action Key". In Ubuntu, that key is the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. If you hold that key pressed, you will easily be able to move the window freely up and down by clicking on it and dragging it, with <kbd>Super</kbd> pressed. Thus, you can reach any parts you need.

The "Window Action Key" can be changed from <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or can be disabled in Gnome Tweaks (not installed by default), Windows tab.

Only for windows that can be resized: holding the Window Action Key and right-clicking the window anywhere will allow you to resize in a direction determined by where you right click.

2. With the "move" key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

After hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, the window is in "move" mode. You can now just move the window around by moving the mouse cursor. You can also move the window with the arrow keys. Click once or hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit this mode.

In a similar way, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> is a resize key (if the window can be resized).

Comment: Alt+F7, and left mouse click with mouse move help too.

Comment: @N0rbert indeed, that is the "old style" way which we tend to forget. Arguably even easier if you ask me. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this before. This dialog window could go down, left, and right beyond the screen but never up which is what I want as I want to reach the bottom of the window.